# Orthogonal Projection Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $w_1,...,w_n$ be any basis of the subspace $W \subset
>  \mathbb{R^m}$. Let $A = (w_1,...,w_n)$ be the $m$ x $n$ matrix whose
>   columns are the basis vectors, so that $W = rngA$ and $rankA=n$. Let
>   $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ be the corresponding projection matrix.
>
> a.) Prove that the orthogonal projection of $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ onto
>   $w \in W$ is obtained by multiplying by the projection matrix: $w=Pv$.
>
> b.) Show that if $A=QR$, then $P = QQ^T$. Why is $P \ne I$?

How will I be able to prove these?

Comment: Are there some conditions on $Q$ and $R$?

Comment: For the first part consider $\operatorname{rng}(P)$ and $Pw_i$.

Comment: @copper.hat To me it sounds like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

Comment: Or alternatively, note that $v$ is a solution to the problem $\min_{w \in W} \|w-v\|^2 = \min_x \|Ax-v\|^2$ and look at the first order optimality conditions at the solution...

Comment: I see now, he is using the reduced QR decomposition where $R$ is square. I think of the Q in the QR decomposition as being unitary...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For part b), note that $A^T A = R^T Q^T Q R = R^T R$, so 
\begin{align*}
P &= QR(R^T R)^{-1} R^T Q^T \\
&= Q R R^{-1} R^{-T} R^T Q^T \\
&= Q Q^T.
\end{align*}

For part a), suppose $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and let $\hat{b} = A \hat{x}$ be the projection of $b$ onto $W$.  The residual $b - A \hat{x}$ is orthogonal to $W$, hence it is orthogonal to each of the columns of $A$.  This tells us that
\begin{align*}
&A^T (b - A \hat{x}) = 0 \\
\implies & A^T A \hat{x} = A^T b \\
\implies& \hat{x} = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b \\
\implies& A \hat{x} = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b \\
\implies& \hat{b} = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b.
\end{align*}

This shows that the matrix $P = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ projects onto $W$.

Answer (score 4):

(a) Let $1 \le i \le n$, we have by noting that $Ae_i = w_i$ ($e_i$ the standard unit vector)
\begin{align*}
  Pw_i &= A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tw_i\\
   &= A(A^TA)^{-1}A^TAe_i\\
   &= Ae_i\\
   &= w_i
\end{align*}
so $P$ acts as the identity on $W$. Now let $z \in W^\bot$, then we have 
\[ A^Tz = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^Tz = \sum_i 0  =0 \]
so $Pz = 0$ and $P$ acts as $0$ on $W^\bot$. That is, $P$ is the orthogonal projection on $W$.

(b) Let $A = QR$ be the QR-decomposition, that is $Q$ is $m \times n$ with orthogonal columns and $R$ is upper triangular. We have
\begin{align*}
  A^TA &= R^TQ^TQR\\
  (A^TA)^{-1} &= R^{-1}(Q^TQ)^{-1}R^{-T}\\
  A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T &= QRR^{-1}(Q^TQ)^{-1}R^{-T}R^TQ^T\\
        &= Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T
\end{align*}
As $Q$ has orthogonal columns $Q^TQ = \mathrm{Id}$, and therefore $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T = QQ^T$. $P \ne \mathrm{Id}$ holds exactly iff $n < m$ as then $P$ is a projection onto a proper subspace.